# Can questions about "What Server do I need to run X" be asked on Gaming.SE?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

In the Gaming.SE FaQ it states:

> If your question generally covers things such as...**Game-specific hardware and utilities**...then you are in the right place to ask your question!

Over at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) there's be a few (since-deleted) questions about gaming servers such as "what sort of server do I need to run a 25-player Minecraft Server". If this is phrased correctly, such as "I have a server with [specs], can I run a Minecraft/Battlefield/Other" reliably, would that be allowed here?

I've been close to suggestion the OP drops into chat, although gaming.se chat may not be as "lax" as ServerFault.chat in regards to on/off-topicness.

Comment: Chat has to be on-topic? xD

Comment: @Shinrai, that's why it depends on the site ;)

Comment: Trust me, chat is lax enough.  The very definition of our chat is "Stuff we don't let on the main site".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[While we welcome questions about game server software *in general*, and have several regarding running Minecraft servers in particular](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servers), the specific example you cite would probably be closed here, not because it's about a Server, but because it's **Shopping Advice**, and generally not something we deal with.

If you have questions about how to configure, run, or manage a Minecraft, Battlefield, or Whatever Server (that are specific to those applications. Please don't send us questions about how to do more general server stuff just because it happens to eventually be used to play Minecraft), by all means, send them over.

But don't send us the '*Is this Hardware enough to run X?*' stuff. We already don't want those for the *client* side regarding every last game -  there's no reason the server side is special.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification :)