# Is it OK to ask how to setup a gaming server?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I asked a question about how to setup a Black Ops server, but it immediately got voted down:

[How to setup a dedicated Call of Duty Black Ops Server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/308563/how-to-setup-a-dedicated-call-of-duty-black-ops-server)

Is this question not appropriate for this site?

Comment: Initial thought is that it should be on topic. I don't remember any metas offhand disallowing this but I will have to do a bit of digging to be sure.

Answer (score 4):

Questions about game servers are [on-topic](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3400/can-questions-about-what-server-do-i-need-to-run-x-be-asked-on-gaming-se?rq=1), if they're specific enough. ServerFault is not the right place for game server specific questions, so they would fit in here just fine.

In this particular case I'd still vote for off-topic, though. CoD Black Ops is one of the games with exclusive rights given to a certain provider ([Reference](http://www.ign.com/articles/2010/09/10/black-ops-dedicated-servers-come-with-a-catch)). So if you're not hosting it there it's not supported by the publisher = it's not on-topic anymore.

Comment: Last paragraph sounds like the basis of an answer, and not a close vote reason...

Comment: @Robotnik if the answer is "no way", then yes it could be posted as such. Otherwise it would still be OT, since hosting an own server not provided by that one server provider violates the ToS.

Comment: Why can't the answer give setup instructions from that hosting provider if that's the only legal way? *"It's not (legally) possible to roll your own, the official way requires you to use this provider, here's how to do that..."*

Comment: @Robotnik when you order game servers like that they're already good to go. The question is about installing a server, which is done automatically. An instruction about how to click a few buttons seems superfluous.

Comment: @dly Does that make us unable to answer the question then? There's a clear answer, we ought to provide it if we can.

Comment: @dly It's my experience that answers that go the extra mile are more highly regarded. It may be superfluous to youself (and me) or anyone that has moderate understanding of computers and hosting, but for a lot of people out there, that isn't the case. At the very least linking to the *actual* hosting provider so they can follow the instructions from there would help (which is why I linked it in the comments on your answer - feel free to incorporate it). Ultimately it's up to you, just a suggestion :-)

Comment: @Robotnik Ok, linking to the provider makes sense. I didn't do that, because i didn't want to advertise for it. My bad. About the answer I still disagree with answering how to *order* a game server when it was asked how to *install* one, which will never be the case when using a game server provider like this one. Answering with a *configuration* guide will at the very least require some info about the game modes the server is supposed to run. But then again, ranked games only have very limited config options.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf the answer is already there, because it's just not possible to install a server using that game hoster. They do it for you.